How to aggressively smooth a sculpt along a stroke?
So, I have this sculpt that was created by some very aggressive carving:

Unfortunately, as can be seen there is a lot of bumpiness along the axis of the sculpt. I'm trying to reduce this, but smoothing doesn't do a very good job, and does significantly change the cross-sectional profile, which I don't want. Everything else just seems to move the bumpiness in or out.
How can I crush the bumpiness, but only along a stroke? Roughly, I want to go from having ridges/"waviness" perpendicular to the long axis to having ridges parallel to the axis while changing the overall shape as little as possible.

hello, what does it give if you go into Edit mode, select all and top bar > Vetex > Smooth Vertices?

@moonboots, same as the Smooth tool, I expect; because it has no directionality, it'll mess up the profile. I think what I need is a smooth tool that gives weight to the neighbor vertices according to their angle relative to the stroke.
